# Taking too much time in loading phone device contact list in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am loading mobile device contact list in Cordova android application.Its Loading and displaying fine except the huge amount of time .For say `300` contact list it is taking `6 minutes` of time which is very very bad for the user experience of the app.

Is there any way by which i can reduce the loading time and pace up the app.Any suggestion will be helpfull for me ..Thanks..

Here is updated code..

```
function drawListContent(contactListArray, filter) {

    var contactList;
    if (contactListArray) {
        contListContainer.innerHTML = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < contactListArray.length; i++) {

            if (typeof(contactListArray[i]) == "string") {
                contListContainer.innerHTML += contactListArray[i];                
            } 

            else {
                contListContainer.appendChild(contactListArray[i]);
            }

        }
    }

    contactList = getElementChildren(contListContainer);     

    for (var i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++) {          

            filter = filter.toLowerCase();
            var name = getDisplayedName(contactList[i]).toLowerCase().split(" ");

                for (var j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {

                    if (name[j].indexOf(filter) === 0) {

                        contactList[i].style.display = "block";
                        break;

                    } 
            }                 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used this a lot of times but this issue never happens. Do one thing, comment all the lines inside `contactSuccess` and insert an alert. If its fast then the culprit is your `contactSuccess` functions.

Comment: @SujataChanda As advised by you i commented all the lines in `contactSuccess ` and put an alert and i was able to get the alert message at once .It came very fast ..Why is those lines making the application slow .Any Solution ?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing on those functions as you have given those code. You need to debug your code to see what is happening.

Comment: @SujataChanda Mam i have updated my `formContactList` function .Could you see please where is this code consuming so much time .I am very new in this field ..Needed your assistance

Comment: Need `sortContactsList` and `drawListContent` also.

Comment: @SujataChanda I have updated my post with the required functions .Please have a look.Thanks

Comment: You can omit the `sortContactsList` function as Contacts plugin returns you the sorted list. Check whether it improves the performance or not.

Comment: Also in `drawListContent` function you have 2 for loops. If possible check whether you can do it in one loop or not.

Comment: @SujataChanda Commenting `sortContactsList ` does not really worked out .Still its taking time to display the list..

Comment: @SujataChanda What i can remove in `drawListContent `..Any advice or guesses?

Comment: You can remove your last loop and instead bring all the codes inside your 1st loop.

Comment: @SujataChanda.Ok I am trying to optimize the code.I do have query that approx. how much time it will take to display `300` contacts ?

Comment: Showing 300 contacts should take less than a minute. Also in `formContactList` you have a  loop. Just try to reduce the number of loops and make all your work in one loop if possible.

Comment: @SujataChanda Actually I tried removing the codes from the `drawListContent ` function but not able to do it ..My contact list is not visible now ..Any suggestion by seeing the code of the function..to optimize.Actually i do not have any debugging toll available with me ..I can test it by installing it on my mobile device So needed your help

Comment: Your `drawListContent` can easily be inserted into `formContactList`. Just put all the codes of `drawListContent` into the forloop of `formContactList` and re-ordering some lines will make it work.

Comment: @SujataChanda I followed your advice and tried o reduce the `drawListContent` function the code of which i have updated in the also but i was not able to remove the two for loop ..Still the two for loop is present and so is my issue.Any suggestion to merg the code into one ?

Comment: No it is not possible for me to check since I need to know all your needs and need to see the whole code, which is not possible.

Comment: @SujataChanda yes i can understand .Okay i have one query ..How to show any app into Phone device Contacts dialer option like we see `skype, Whatapp etc`.What is the keywork for that ..I will be gratefull if you point me to the appropriate link

Comment: I have never implemented that, can't help you.